# Run WinSCP script from bat file as different user

Tags: windows, winscp, runas

could anybody help me with this please:

I can successfully call a WinSCP script from a bat file like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /script="script_file_path.txt"
```

I can also successfully open a program such as notepad as a different user like this:

```
runas /user:my_user@my_domain "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
```

However I cannot call a WinSCP script as a different user by doing this:

```
runas /user:my_user@my_domain "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /script="script_file_path.txt"
```

When I run the code, it does nothing. It doesn't prompt for a password, open WinSCP or run the script. If I add a pause at the end to see what is on the cmd screen it is a list of prompts and their descriptions for the runas command.

Many thanks in advance.

James

Comment: The problem is that the /script=".." parameter is sent to the runas command, not the winscp command. Put your winscp line in a .cmd file and use runas to call that file instead.

Comment: THANK YOU so much -- all working now.  This means I can automate a lot of tasks on a virtual machine and save myself a lot of time -- much appreciated.  Cheers, James

Comment: Thank you, I think so, yes.